# How to run multiple python versions in one project

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, pyaudio

I've a digital assistant mega project which needs **PyAudio** for Speech Recognition lib which isn't supported after python 3.6, and I've some features and packages/modules used that are incompatible with python 3.6.

This drives me to the question that how can I achieve the following:

> 1. Run specific files of a project with some earlier Python version **(Python 3.6)**
> 2. Other set of files of same project with some other python version **(Python 3.10)**.

##### Note: These files will run simultaneously.

Comment: You run two different processes and use a form of [IPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html).